# How can I un-seize the front suspension on my bike?

Tags: mountain-bike, trek

I am getting a 2005 Trek 4300 from my friend for free. I would like to fix up this bike so I can get it on the trails. Right now it only has one tire and no chain. He's going to put this bike back together but I want to fix the front suspension. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  When you say "fix the front suspension" do you mean it needs maintenance or do you mean you want to replace it?

Comment: I mean it needs maintenance because I would like to get this bike up and running without it being such an expensive fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this bike has an RST Gila fork.

You can search RST Gila Service on youtube to see what's going on inside. There are a few videos, I'm not going to watch them for you.

It isn't the worlds best suspension fork so you will want to know you can get a replacement if you find it can't be fixed (broken or worn parts, corrosion) when you get it apart.

Comment: Ok. I'll bring it to Piche's and see if they can change that for me. Thanks for the help!